# Formula or rule of thumb to estimate filesystem planning with BtrFS snapshots (SLES or similar)

Tags: snapshot, sles, btrfs, capacity-planning

SLES features BtrFS for the root filesystem, combined with automatic ("numbered") snapshots performed before and after updates. If your system fails, you can boot from an older snapshot (using an older kernel).

That's all nice in theory, but I have practical issues/questions:

1. How big should the filesystem be (e.g. assuming you won't "use" more than 20GB)?
2. When also wanting to use "timeline" snapshots, what are the recommended settings to keep snapshot disk usage "within bounds"?

For example I use the following snapper settings:

```sh
# grep '^[^#]' /etc/snapper/configs/root
SUBVOLUME="/"
FSTYPE="btrfs"
QGROUP="1/0"
SPACE_LIMIT="0.5"
FREE_LIMIT="0.2"
ALLOW_USERS=""
ALLOW_GROUPS=""
SYNC_ACL="no"
BACKGROUND_COMPARISON="yes"
NUMBER_CLEANUP="yes"
NUMBER_MIN_AGE="1800"
NUMBER_LIMIT="2-10"
NUMBER_LIMIT_IMPORTANT="4-10"
TIMELINE_CREATE="yes"
TIMELINE_CLEANUP="yes"
TIMELINE_MIN_AGE="1800"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_HOURLY="10"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_DAILY="5"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_WEEKLY="3"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_MONTHLY="3"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_YEARLY="2"
EMPTY_PRE_POST_CLEANUP="yes"
EMPTY_PRE_POST_MIN_AGE="1800"
```

I mean: Ideally I would want to spend 50% of the planned disk usage for snapshots, so how should I tune the settings then?

Here's an example of snapshots created (the list is likely to grow over time):

```text
# snapper list
    # | Type   | Pre # | Date                     | User | Used Space | Cleanup  | Description              | Userdata
------+--------+-------+--------------------------+------+------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------
   0  | single |       |                          | root |            |          | current                  |
   1* | single |       | Tue Jan 24 12:35:33 2023 | root | 144.00 KiB |          | first root filesystem    |
  27  | single |       | Thu Jan 26 10:14:39 2023 | root | 325.28 MiB |          | Installation DP CM 11.02 |
  42  | single |       | Thu Feb  2 14:00:01 2023 | root | 492.13 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
5181  | single |       | Fri Sep  1 00:00:01 2023 | root | 172.21 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
5274  | pre    |       | Mon Sep  4 11:26:42 2023 | root | 102.06 MiB | number   | zypp(ruby.ruby2.5)       | important=yes
5275  | post   |  5274 | Mon Sep  4 11:29:41 2023 | root | 194.42 MiB | number   |                          | important=yes
5917  | single |       | Sun Oct  1 00:00:01 2023 | root |  13.92 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6172  | pre    |       | Wed Oct 11 14:51:34 2023 | root |   1.23 MiB | number   | yast online_update       |
6175  | pre    |       | Wed Oct 11 14:53:16 2023 | root |  97.12 MiB | number   | zypp(ruby.ruby2.5)       | important=yes
6176  | post   |  6175 | Wed Oct 11 14:56:43 2023 | root | 304.00 KiB | number   |                          | important=yes
6177  | post   |  6172 | Wed Oct 11 14:56:54 2023 | root | 256.00 KiB | number   |                          |
6178  | pre    |       | Wed Oct 11 14:58:37 2023 | root | 928.00 KiB | number   | zypp(zypper)             | important=yes
6179  | post   |  6178 | Wed Oct 11 14:58:47 2023 | root |   1.30 MiB | number   |                          | important=yes
6621  | single |       | Mon Oct 30 00:00:01 2023 | root |   6.52 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6669  | single |       | Wed Nov  1 00:00:01 2023 | root |   6.50 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6789  | single |       | Mon Nov  6 00:00:01 2023 | root |   6.47 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6933  | single |       | Sun Nov 12 00:00:01 2023 | root |   6.20 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6957  | single |       | Mon Nov 13 00:00:01 2023 | root |   5.84 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
6981  | single |       | Tue Nov 14 00:00:01 2023 | root |   3.48 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7005  | single |       | Wed Nov 15 00:00:01 2023 | root |   2.91 MiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7029  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 00:00:01 2023 | root | 464.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7032  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 03:00:01 2023 | root |  16.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7033  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 04:00:01 2023 | root |  16.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7034  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 05:00:01 2023 | root |  64.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7035  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 06:00:01 2023 | root |  16.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7036  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 07:00:01 2023 | root |  16.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7037  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 08:00:01 2023 | root |  32.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7038  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 09:00:01 2023 | root |  80.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7039  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 10:00:01 2023 | root | 128.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7040  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 11:00:01 2023 | root | 272.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7041  | pre    |       | Thu Nov 16 11:50:58 2023 | root | 512.00 KiB | number   | yast online_update       |
7042  | pre    |       | Thu Nov 16 11:52:45 2023 | root |   1.27 MiB | number   | zypp(ruby.ruby2.5)       | important=yes
7043  | post   |  7042 | Thu Nov 16 11:56:35 2023 | root | 560.00 KiB | number   |                          | important=yes
7044  | post   |  7041 | Thu Nov 16 11:56:42 2023 | root | 464.00 KiB | number   |                          |
7045  | pre    |       | Thu Nov 16 11:58:15 2023 | root | 768.00 KiB | number   | zypp(zypper)             | important=yes
7046  | post   |  7045 | Thu Nov 16 11:58:27 2023 | root | 320.00 KiB | number   |                          | important=yes
7047  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 12:00:01 2023 | root | 176.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
7048  | single |       | Thu Nov 16 13:00:01 2023 | root |  32.00 KiB | timeline | timeline                 |
```